# how do I run godot engine on my nvidia graphic card?

Tags: nvidia, intel, engine

Godot3.0.6 is using Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 and I want it to run on Nvidia card.
Is there any way to change the default graphic card to Nvidia card?

Comment: What kind of graphic setup are you using? Is it a laptop with hybrid graphic or a desktop?